# grid-gap only updates the width of one side

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

As you can see, when I change the `grid-gap`, only the width of `1`, `3` and `4` are updated.
The width of `2` is not updated at all.
I want it to update the width of `1` and the width of `2`, `3` and `4`.

The demo of MDN shows that it's possible to resize all items accordingly.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Here's my code

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 20px;    /* Try to change this, width of 2 isn't updated */
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  transition: gap 0.3s linear;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px
}

.child-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}


.child-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the number 2 to get smaller? if so, the numbers 3,4 would not be symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Problem:**

It's not easy to see it from outside but if you can [Examine the Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts) in Firefox developer tools you can see the difference.

[image: Examining the current Grid]

You can notice that the width of the two columns of 2 is changing yet the parent remains constant because it is spanning them both and breaking it would make the grid asymmetrical.

---

### **Solution:**

You can use this [Grid Generator](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/) and create some changes to the code for the following setup:

[image: 2fr + 1fr + 1fr + 1fr + 1fr]

Now `1` spans two fractions of the layout, `2` spans four fractions while `3` and `4` spans two fractions each. In this way, the whole structure is symmetrical.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px; /* Try to change this, width of 2 isn't updated */
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  transition: grid-gap 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover {
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.child-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.child-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 6;
}

.child-3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4;
}

.child-4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child child-3">3</div>
  <div class="child child-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the width of (2) include a gap so its width is `2fr + gap`. changing the gap will also change the `fr` and the width will remain constant.

in this case `1fr = (500px - 2*gap)/4` so `2fr + gap = (500px - 2*gap)/2 + gap = 250px`

Change the code and use a different structure where the width of (2) isn't constant:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px; 
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  animation: change 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  grid-column:span 2;
}

.child-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column:span 1;
}


.child-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}

@keyframes change {
   to {
     grid-gap:1px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

In this case `1fr = (500px - 4*gap )/8` and the width of (2) is `4fr + 3*gap = (500px - 4*gap)/2 + 3*gap = 250px + gap` But now the (3) and (4) will be constant because `2fr + gap=(500px - 4*gap)/4 + gap = 125px`

Another structure where all will update:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 30px; 
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  animation: change 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  grid-column:span 3;
}

.child-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column:span 1;
}


.child-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}

@keyframes change {
   to {
     grid-gap:1px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

The (2) will have a width equal to `250px + 2*gap`. (3) and (4) will have a width equal to `125px + 0.5*gap`

Another configuration:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-gap: 30px; 
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  animation: change 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.child {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  grid-column:span 2;
}

.child-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}


.child-2 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 7;
}

@keyframes change {
   to {
     grid-gap:1px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Basically the trick is to avoid having a constant width for your elements.